# Using like button plugin for liking a photo hosted on facebook

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

Is it possible to use the like button plugin ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ) in order to create a like button associated to a photo hosted on facebook ?

For example, when I use this photo for the button : http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151873865243306, it doesn't retrieve the number of likes, and when clicking on the button, the following error is shown :

```
The page at http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151873865243306 could not be reached.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your FB ID instead on "10151873865243306".

Comment: The ID 10151873865243306 is the id of the photo I'd like to use for the like button. The like plugin works with the home page "http://www.facebook.com/cocacola" but not with this photo.. why ?

Comment: @Prakash: DO you have an example of using a fbid instead of a url? No one seems to know how to do this.

Comment: try this method to like the facebook object using fb object id https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbobjectId.'/likes?method=post&'.$fbaccessToken